# Handle the number of threads in an api

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a api which may be used by multiple applications. I want to regulate my api so that I process only a fixed number of requess per application. Suppose app. X is giving some 30 requests and I hvae onl 20 allowed for this particular application to use my api. So I allow only 20 threads and mark others as waiting, similar things should be done for all apis.

What will be the best way to do this.

Comment: Are we talking about a web service API, like in a Java EE container?

Comment: Yes. Do u have any ideas to implement it?

Comment: Not really, just trying to help lead your question to a better answer. "api" is quite a broad term.

Answer (score 2):

How about looking at:

```
ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
```

[Executers on Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a Semaphore.  The class in java is

```
java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
```

Create a semaphore as in

```
mysem = new Semaphore(20);
```

Then in your API you do the following

```
void myAPI()  {
        mysem.acquire();
        //My API logic comes here
        finally {
           mysem.release();
        }
    }
```